# Form $_POST Variables empty in PHP Handler

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I've converted a working form to use Bootstrap's StepWizard and now when the form is submitted via the same Ajax method as with the previous form the PHP handler says **all** variables are null.

**Ajax call**:

```
    // Put the form data into a serialized string and make Ajax call
    var formData = $("#entryForm").serialize();

    console.log(formData);

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/contest/entry/php/formSubmit_TAB_WIZ.php",
        data: formData,
        global: true,   // SHOW MODAL FOR THIS AJAX REQUEST VIA AJAX START/STOP
        success: function (result){
//            console.log('in success function; result=' + result);
//            if (result === 'SUCCESS') {
//                location.href = "/contest/entry/php/printout_TAB_WIZ.php";
                location.href = "/contest/entry/php/formSubmit_TAB_WIZ.php";
//            } else {
//                //alert(result);
//                jqUIAlert(result, false);
//            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //console.log('In error function; jqXHR=' + jqXHR.status);
            //console.log('In error function; textStatus=' + textStatus);
            //console.log('In error function; errorThrown=' + errorThrown);

            //alert('Error processing Ajax request (formSubmit): ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + errorThrown);
            jqUIAlert('Error processing Ajax request (formSubmit): ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + errorThrown, false);
        },
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("input[type=submit]").val('Submit');            
        }
    });
```

The console shows the serialized data just fine (I added line breaks after each parameter for clarity):

```
token=aa5077b808388b52050aba342f11a7c3fd4c9d37ebe9f7e94425edeaf1b20920
&fName=Ross
&lName=Waddell
&phone=555%20555%201212
&email=a%40b.com
&modelName=
&remarks=
&category=
&securedToBase=Yes
&acceptAgrmt=
&g-recaptcha-response=03AGdBq25_SV2ouAUrzAs_QsbEVZcmJUGEXrQXmRYBSQbZhtoyTKwI0xmIodkozOt0l9jntAqqwaJH-QqYWJj_tF127jDbi00XBVv9AGa2nX5wZRf_uj8RuosO7NnGP4i6BiiFi5lPmgau6we_9gKu84QHpFQ-tlB_HtYNouPWtDgyjCeasIo1noqbjfBZz1BsSWhmyCPHDoq9A4P1u_cYWtY67U9jFSFhEimHVNakdpsnnPsSqDW8Uf9puLnZG5EjuKm5RV5kdaNMPH64DGpmJTnQzepz6G2T56_CASy1mYstOmBvSv22p3ZpmY2hUMPkVR_2WdixAdBb_JwQtgyfA6zrfG9FJLo7aQ4gHwQd8n5Zh1M5XMH9HDusrAlopNcPfLtCGyg573T5CwJtTr0wzQuguvlftCL-bT8uDTcpQzj8ZqtV2-XMc5GFDwpeRB2vJKyX2DcIbVHa
```

But my PHP handler throws errors (this is just for one of the $_POST variables):

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: fName in /public_html/contest/entry/php/formSubmit_TAB_WIZ.php on line 35
```

**PHP Handler (formSubmit_TAB_WIZ.php):**

```
<?php 
    // include setConfig
    require_once '../../../../private/contest/include/setConfig.php'; 
    
    // include startSession
    require_once '../../../../private/contest/include/startSession.php';    

    
    startWFsession('entry_form');
        
    $sessionToken = isset($_SESSION['token']) ? bin2hex($_SESSION['token']) : '';
    
    $log->debug('formSubmit.php: starting/loading session', 
    array('file:' => basename(__FILE__), 
            'line#:' => __LINE__,
            'session_id' => session_id(),
            '$_SESSION["token"]' => $sessionToken)); 
        
    
    $_SESSION['current_time'] = time();

//    print_r($_POST);
    
//    $post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
//    echo $post_data;
    
    $ip =  getUserIP();  
    $sessionID = session_id();
    
    $log->debug('POST variables from new TAB WIZARD form:', 
            array('file:' => basename(__FILE__), 
                    'line#:' => __LINE__,
                    'session_id' => $sessionID,
                    'IP' => $ip,
                    '$_POST["token"]' => $_POST["token"],
                    '$_POST["fName"]' => $_POST["fName"],
                    '$_POST["lName"]' => $_POST["lName"],
                    '$_POST["phone"]' => $_POST["phone"],
                    '$_POST["email"]' => $_POST["email"],
                    '$_POST["modelEntryList"]' => $_POST["modelEntryList"]
            ));      

    die();
```

What's baffling is the old form still works just fine, using the same Ajax call and similar PHP code (so I know this isn't a case of PHP.ini property values). I've run the new form through an HTML validator and all checks out - all the form names are unique and it is serializing properly.

I've tried to debug this for days with no luck - can someone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**
The HTML for my form submit button:

```
<input type="submit" id="formsubmit" name="mysubmit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" value="Submit">
```

**JS Code to prevent default submission**:

```
    $("#entryForm").on("submit", function(e) {
        // Triggered by form submission: do all field validations
  
        //console.log('In $("#entryForm").on("submit", function() ...');
  
        // Disallow browser form submission
        e.preventDefault();    

        var oForm = document.forms["entryForm"];
        //var oForm = $('form[name="entryForm"]');  Easier to use pure JS here
          
        // User has to check Terms and Conditions for new entry
        if(!oForm.elements["acceptAgrmt"].checked) {
            oForm.elements["acceptAgrmt"].focus();
            //alert("Please accept the Terms and Conditions.");
            jqUIAlert("Please accept the Terms and Conditions.", false);
            return false;
        }
  
        if (validateForm(oForm)) {
            //console.log('Validation succeeded.');
  
            // Validation succeeded, so now explicitly call reCAPTCHA check
            grecaptcha.execute();  
        } else {
            //console.log('Validation failed; preventing form submission');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**EDIT2**
Looking at the network traffic in Chrome's developer tools I see to lines for my PHP handler (formSubmit_TAB_WIZ.php) but only one looks like a POST when I filter by 'method:POST'. But no matter what I do in terms of how I invoke the Ajax call, I see two records in my PHP logger: the first one has all the input values, and the second has all null. What the what is going on here?

[image]

**EDIT3**
Looks like the 2nd request is a GET - but why?

```
192.168.1.18 - - [05/Jan/2021:20:28:16 -0500] "POST /contest/entry/php/formSubmit_TAB_WIZ.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1907 "http://wonderfest:8000/contest/entry/entryForm_TAB_WIZ_v4.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"
192.168.1.18 - - [05/Jan/2021:20:28:16 -0500] "GET /contest/entry/php/formSubmit_TAB_WIZ.php HTTP/1.1" 200 238 "http://wonderfest:8000/contest/entry/entryForm_TAB_WIZ_v4.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: How is the JS code being triggered? Is it on the click of a form's submit button? If so, have you cancelled the form submission event?

Comment: surley `'fName' => $_POST["fName"],` NOT `'$_POST["fName"]' => $_POST["fName"],` and ditto for all the others

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Yes, I have e.preventDefault(); in my     $("#entryForm").on("submit", function(e) {}). That function is the same for both the old form and the new one, and hasn't changed.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: that's just so I can see in my custom log file where the value is coming from (it adds the first part as text and then the second part is the actual value)

Comment: I attached a debugger and it looks like the form is posting twice - the first time I can see the correct $_POST variable values, but on the 2nd they are all null. Why am I getting two form submits?

Comment: Looks like the 2nd request is a GET - but why?

Answer (score 0):

The GET is coming from the redirect in the Ajax success function:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/contest/entry/php/formSubmit_TAB_WIZ.php",
    data: formData,
    global: true,   // SHOW MODAL FOR THIS AJAX REQUEST VIA AJAX START/STOP
    success: function (result){
        console.log('in success function; result=' + result);
        if (result === 'SUCCESS') {
            location.href = "/contest/entry/php/formSubmit_TAB_WIZ.php";
        } else {
            //alert(result);
            jqUIAlert(result, false);
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        jqUIAlert('Error processing Ajax request (formSubmit): ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + errorThrown, false);
    },
    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("input[type=submit]").val('Submit');            
    }
});
```

I wanted to see the variable values on the page, so I used the same PHP handler here but of course that turns into a GET. So, the first request was actually working fine, but the errors in my php_error.log were from the 2nd GET request since naturally the $_POST variables were null.